# Angular Material MatSelect: How to display an option which is not contained in option list?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

Given following setup with a reactive form:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="selectFormCtrl">
        <!-- Option search field -->
        <ngx-mat-select-search *ngIf="canFilter" [formControl]="optionsFilter"></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async | slice:0:MAX_ITEMS" [value]="option.value">
            {{ option.text }}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngIf="showNothingFound()" [value]="" disabled>Nothing found</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Problem: There is `slice:0:MAX_ITEMS` where I would like to truncate the list. E.g. long lists like country lists the user may rather type into the search field in order to filter the options. But if there is an option set which does not appear in the list itself, the component won't show that option.

Idea: Make sure the selected option is always contained in `filteredOptions`.

Is there a more elegant/simple solution to actually set a selected option in MatSelect, so that it shows a value in any case?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use mat-autocomplete instead where you can easily set the value of the input field to anything even if it does not appear in the list.

Comment: how about adapting the way the `filteredOptions` are calculated and explicitly include the selected options? you could listen to any selection change to update the filtered options

Answer (score 1):

you could create an observable of the filtered, sliced options:

```js
filteredOptionsSliced$ = combineLatest(
  this.filteredOptions, 
  this.selectFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null))
).pipe(map((filteredOptions, selectedOption) => {
  const slicedOptions = filteredOptions.slice(0, MAX_ITEMS);
  if (selectedOption && !slicedOptions.find(slicedOption => slicedOption.value === selectedOption.value)) {
    slicedOptions.push(selectedOption);
  }
  return slicedOptions;
}))
```

and use it in your template without the slice pipe:

```html
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsSliced$ | async" [value]="option.value">
```

Comment: Thx - I ended up with a similar solution. Basically ensure that the selected option is always contained in the list.